# Hazelcast error when aggregating using SqlPredicate

Tags: java, aggregate, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to perform searches and aggregations on maps in Hazelcast using an SqlPredicate predicate.  When searching like below, the SqlPredicate works perfectly:

```
imap = //get map from Hazelcast
Collection c = imap.values(new SqlPredicate("field=value"));
```

But, if I try to do the following aggregation, I get a ClassCastException:

```
imap = //get map from Hazelcast

PropertyExtractor<-,-> pe = x -> x.getValue();
SqlPredicate p = new SqlPredicate("field=value");

Supplier<-,-,-> s = Supplier.fromPredicate(p, Supplier.all(pe));
int x = imap.aggregate(s, Aggregations.integerMax());
```

I also tried creating my own custom predicate that is a wrapper around the SqlPredicate:

```
public static MyPredicate implements Predicate<-,-> {
    private SqlPredicate pred;

    public MyPredicate(String s){
        pred = new SqlPredicate(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Entry<-,-> arg0){
        return pred.apply(arg0);
    }
}
```

This results in a NullPointerException and the apply() method is never reached.

Is this a bug in Hazelcast?  Or is there a reason why a SqlPredicate cannot be used to create a Supplier?  SqlPredicate implements the Predicate interface, so I would assume it should work.

I am currently using SqlPredicate while searching, so I would like to be able to use the same predicate to filter when aggregating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlPredicates (and Predicates / PredicateBuilder predicates) are currently not supported inside an aggregation. However you can implement your own Predicate for such simple calls. I guess it'll be fixed in 3.6 as far as I remember.

Comment: Thanks!  I will just create my own predicate.  Do you know if there is a timeframe for release of 3.6?

Comment: Not sure about the release date but if I'm not mistaken in late autumn :)